# How do I add a scrollbar to a JFrame with setLayout(null)?

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, jscrollpane

I have some components which I need to use `setBounds()` on, hence the reason why I'm using the `setLayout(null)`.

But some of my components are out the window(below the Y-axis). I was wondering if there is a way to add a scrollbar to navigate down the window so as to see all the remaining components. A screenshot of my window is below.

Output of my window image:

[image]

Comment: You don’t need to use a null layout and you shouldn’t use a null layout.  If you have a vertical list of information, place it in a JList or a JTable, and place the JList or JTable inside a JScrollPane.

Comment: Refer to [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: @AndrewThompson can u please post a copy of this code. Thx

Answer (score 0):

That GUI would be simple to produce using layouts. Put the component displaying the list (which looks well suited to being a `JTable`, given the two pieces of data per row / line) into a `JScrollPane`. Put the scroll pane into the `CENTER` of a `BorderLayout`. Put the red label into the `PAGE_START` of the border layout. Then .. oh wait, the job is done!

This is what it might look like (using a `JTextArea` instead of a table).

[image]

> can u please post a copy of this code.

Try implementing it based on the instructions above. If there is a problem, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are refering to the items in the scrolling area as components, and not as texts in a JTextArea, please have a look at the below.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Mainframe {
    private JFrame f;
    Box box;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Mainframe().go();
    }

    private void go() {
        box = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Possible Paths and Total Distances");
        label.setForeground(Color.RED);

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            box.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 2)));// creates space between the components
            box.add(new JLabel(i + " : " + rand.nextInt(10000)));
        }

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(box);
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(box.getComponent(0).getPreferredSize());
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(dim.height * 2); // adjusts scrolling speed
        //scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(640, 480);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```